# How to vectorize this loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vectorization

I don't have much experience in R. I am trying to write a Gibbs sampler where I have a for loop like this:

```
for (iNum in 1:totNum) {
    rateNum <- Y3[iNum]
    if(Y3[iNum] > 0) {
        yStar3[iNum] <- rtnorm(1, mean = Mean3[iNum], sd = sqrt(Var3), 
                 lower = gz[rateNum], upper = gz[rateNum + 1])
    } else if(Y3[iNum] == 0) {
    yStar3[iNum] <- rtnorm(1, mean = Mean3[iNum], sd = sqrt(Var3), 
                  lower = -Inf, upper = Inf);
    }
}
```

This is taking too much of time. I tried to use `lapply` but that also is not fast enough. Is there a way to vectorize this loop?

Thank you and best regards!!

Comment: I was going to say yes, since `rtnorm` is vectorized, but you appear to be using different truncation values (upper, lower) for each value and that argument is, I think, not vectorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a problem without some values for your variables, but what you're wanting to do is fairly straight-forward.  You want to stick with all vectorized statements for this and try not to hog too much memory.  This is the basic strategy:

**Step 1**: Figure out how to calculate all your numbers.

```
# The number of values you need from 'rtnorm'
sum(Y3 > 0)
sum(Y3 == 0)

# The means you need from the 'Mean3' array
Mean3[Y3 > 0]
Mean3[Y3 == 0]

# Lower and upper limits for Y3 > 0
gz[Y3[Y3 > 0]]
gz[Y3[Y3 > 0] + 1]
```

**Step 2**: Use these values on a vector filter of yStar3.  I can't be absolutely sure all of my syntax is perfect without some sample data and variable values, but it should look something like this:

```
yStar3[Y3 > 0] <- rtnorm(
  sum(Y3 > 0), 
  mean = Mean3[Y3 > 0], 
  sd = sqrt(Var3), 
  lower = gz[Y3[Y3 > 0]], 
  upper = gz[Y3[Y3 > 0] + 1])

yStar3[Y3 == 0] <- rtnorm(
  sum(Y3 == 0), 
  mean = Mean3[Y3 == 0], 
  sd = sqrt(Var3), 
  lower = -Inf, 
  upper = Inf)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your kind responses! I have been able to get it working and improve the speed significantly. A single iteration of this step now takes 0.05 second instead of 1.5 seconds, in effect saving hours of computational time for the overall algorithm!!!

Comment: Glad we could help.  As you can probably tell, optimization questions are actually pretty interesting to a lot of us.  Next time, if you can provide some sample data and ask for optimization rather than vectorization, you may get even more interest and activity on your question.

Comment: Also, if you've reached your solution, go ahead and pick an answer that you feel best answered or was most helpful in answering your original question by clicking the check-mark next to one of the answers.  This will be helpful to others who find this page in the future and will close the question.

Comment: Sure Next time I will provide some data with my questions. This was first time I was asking in this forum !! Regarding the "best answer" I wanted to pick more than one answer as useful but apparently I can not do that so initially I did not pick any

Comment: Yeah, there are often multiple good answers to a single question, so you just have to pick one arbitrarily.  None of us are offended if you don't pick our answer.

Comment: Hi, can you help me see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054971/how-to-debug-for-my-gibbs-sampler-of-bayesian-regression-in-r? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So, it doesn't appear that you have dependencies between iterations which makes it pretty straightforward to vectorize

```
  lhs = rtnorm(length(Y3), mean = Mean3, sd = sqrt(Var3), lower = gz[Y3],
              upper = gz[Y3 + 1])
  rhs = rtnorm(length(Y3), mean=Mean3, sd = sqrt(Var3), lower=-Inf, upper=Inf)

  ifelse(Y3 > 0, lhs, rhs)
```

The issue here is that rtnorm has to be vectorized over its input parameters, mean, lower, and upper. That might not be the case, in which case you'll have to do more work.

Comment: Beat me to it.  I believe `rtnorm` is a truncated normal distribution from the msm package, so it should already be vectorized.

Comment: Hi, can you help me see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054971/how-to-debug-for-my-gibbs-sampler-of-bayesian-regression-in-r? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to generate the two halves of the conditional and select which on you want.  The `mean` parameter will take the vector means, so you get something like this:

```
yStar3 <- ifelse(
  Y3 > 0,
    rtnorm(totNum, mean=Mean3, sd=sqrt(Var3), lower=gz[ratenum], upper=gz[rateNum+1]),
    rtnorm(totNum, mean=Mean3, sd=sqrt(Var3), lower=-Inf, upper=Inf))
```

You'll have to refine the `ifelse`, potentially with an additional condition for the case where Y3 is less than zero, but this is the general idea.

Update: @hadley suggests moving the ifelse inside the rtnorm:

```
yStar3 <- rtnorm(totNum, mean=Mean3, sd=sqrt(Var3),
  lower=ifelse(Y3>0,gz[rateNum], -Inf),
  upper=ifelse(Y3>0,gz[rateNum+1], Inf))
```

Now there is essentially zero unnecessary computation going on.

Update: Of course, 1 is wrong, as commenters noted; it should be totNum instead.

Comment: `ifelse` has to compute both statements completely; you're be better off using it inside `rtnorm`

Comment: Won't you need to specify a number other than '1' for the 'rtnorm' function?  The first argument tells it how many values to return.

Comment: `rtnorm(1,...)` should be `rtnorm(length(Y3),...)` everywhere.

Comment: Hi, can you help me see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054971/how-to-debug-for-my-gibbs-sampler-of-bayesian-regression-in-r? Thank you.